# Data Validation from script but using a named range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure a way to add *DataValidation* with named range name as "Range" value. Using *getRangeByName* in *requireValueInRange* provides me with just "*A1:A50*" while i need to find a way to put "*SampleRange*" (which is range name) in it's place. It is possible to do manually but i have 300 rows to update one by one and i need a way to automate it.

```
function ValidationNamedRange() {
    var NameSpace = "SampleRange";
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(NameSpace).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In Google Apps Script syntax casing is important, `GetRangeByName` and `RequireValueInRange` will throw  syntax errors.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't show the problem. Add a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a named range for a data validation programmatically (in Google apps script) in a Google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729561/how-to-set-a-named-range-for-a-data-validation-programmatically-in-google-apps)

Answer (score 0):

> GetRangeByName outputs the range as A1 notation

This is wrong. Besides the correct syntax is getRangeByName(), this method returns a Range object.

**Example**

The following will add a data validation to the specified named range.

1. First create a named range, and set its name to `NamedRange1`
2. Execute the following script

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     var name = 'NamedRange1';
     var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(name);
     var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireNumberBetween(5, 10).build();
     rng.setDataValidation(rule);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I guess i wasn't clear enough. I need to find a way to add a Named Range name as range value in validation. When i use "GetRangeByName(SampleRange)" I get data validation with "A3:B400" and I need a way to have "SampleRange" instead. Is there a way to create DataValidation rule that will work like this?

Comment: this adds dataValidation on a range, but the question is actually, how to add datavalidation that adds a dropdown verifying the content 'against' a named range

it's easy enough to generate a range, but it will always translate to the A1 notation within the datavalidator as far as i know, I have not been able to do this either as of yet.